# Anaysis of survial data with time varying covariates

Tags: logistic, survival, panel-data, binary-data

I have the survival data like following:

```
-----------------------
ID time death var1 var2
1  1    0     3.4  5
1  2    0     4.2  6
...
1  1092 0     5.0  2
1  1093 1     4.1  3
2  1    0     8.1  3
2  2    0     1.4  1
------------------------
```

Number of unique ID is only 10, but I have thousands records for each ID.
My questions are: 
1: What analysis should I do when my interest is to estimate the effects of var1 to death, at each time? I am assuming the effect of var1 to death varies over time. Problem is that when table is sliced at each time, I have only 10 observations and it is difficult to do logistic regression. 
2: Can I do multiple regression, time as response variable and var1 as explanatory variable? Here I use time as response, so I am afraid I cannot estimate time varying effect of var1, since time would be used for both as a response and an interaction term.
3: Are there any analysis that efficiently uses within subjects records which are time varying, other than survival analysis? Survival analysis seems to compress within ID recods to 1 record, so currently I do not think using it.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly identified this in the tags as a survival analysis model. The simplest one would be a discrete time survival model, which is just a logit model with death as your dependent variable in your *entire* dataset. The logic is that in that model you look at the chance of surviving the first, second, third, ..., period in which you died period. This is the product of the individual probabilities, and guess what maximum likelihood does... For more see: https://www.iser.essex.ac.uk/files/teaching/stephenj/ec968/pdfs/ec968st6.pdf

You include your preferred function of time and and interaction between time and var1.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I think this pdf refers to the case where
each observation is associated with each person. In my case, each person has many records with covariates that change over time. Would you tell me the analysis that can be used in my case?